# gimme example to create model relations on StrongLoop

Tags: model, strongloop

here i want to create model relations on StrongLoop.
I have this kind of scenario:

1. **Category**:

   - id:1
   - name:history
2. **Book**

   - id:1
   - id_category:1
   - title:american-hustle
   - id_publisher:1
   - --------------------------
   - id:2
   - id_category:1
   - title:american-hustle2
   - id_publisher:2
3. **Publisher**

   - id:1
   - name:Publisher-1
   - --------------------------
   - id:2
   - name:Publisher-2

how can i create model relations like that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find what you need at:

http://strongloop.com/strongblog/defining-and-mapping-data-relations-with-loopback-connected-models/

Basically,

```
// 1-many
Category.hasMany(Book, {as: 'books', foreignKey: 'id_category'});
Publisher.hasMany(Book, {as: 'books', foreignKey: 'id_publisher'});

// belongsTo
Book.belongsTo(Category, {as: 'category', foreignKey: 'id_category'});
Book.belongsTo(Publisher, {as: 'publisher', foreignKey: 'id_publisher'});
```

Depending on how you want to navigate the model relations, you can define one direction or both.